# ng grid horizontal scroll issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

I'm not quite sure if this has been solved already. I've a grid where there a lot of columns. Hence, there is a horizontal scroll bar that shows up which allows you to scroll to the last few columns.

I don't see the columns after a certain number initially when the grid is empty.
With data, I can scroll to the left and see data.

Now if I filter on any one of the columns which didn't show up initially which gives me zero results, I can't scroll back to the column and remove the filter because it's not visible. Please help me. Any help appreciated.

This issue doesn't exist in slick grid on which ng grid is built on.

Thanks

Comment: I too face the same issue.

Comment: I am seeing this issue. I'll reopen your ticket.

Answer (score 4):

Another quick fix is to use a CSS class

```
.ngCanvas {
    min-height: 1px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this may solve the issue ,in ma case when there is no row in the canvas the height becomes 0 and which makes the scroll to disappear and thus we can find when the height becomes zero and replace it with a fixed height.

```
 $scope.canvasStyle = function() {
    if(grid.maxCanvasHt!=0)
    return { "height": grid.maxCanvasHt + "px" };
    else
         return { "height":"3px" };// set height to minimum requirement.

};
```

Comment: The problem is with coulmn and not with the row. when there is more columns few columns at the end are not binded. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884036/horizontal-scrolling-of-ng-grid-2-0-11

Comment: @sms I think thats a different issue