# Horizontal Scrolling of ng-grid - 2.0.11

Tags: c#, css, .net, angularjs, ng-grid

I have a ng-grid in my application. The height and width of the grid is given as auto. I have option to add the column dynamically to the grid. When the number of columns is less there is no problem. But if there is more number of columns then instead of getting Horizontal scrollbar my columns are shrinked in size and all the columns appear in a dirty manner in my grid. The width of the grid is not altered and all the columns are shrinked to fit the grid. What i am missing to get horizontal scrollbar.

**Edit:**
     The above is my original question. Now i am able to get horizontal scrollbar. But only certain columns are visible. When i scroll right i am getting empty grid. The last few coulmns are not binded to  ng-grid. Only the columns that are fit to ng-grid without scrolling are binded. Any solution please !

**Note:**
     I am using ng-grid 2.0.11. Is the version is having this bug?

https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/2071

Comment: Can you post your code? I think the problem is with the width auto, this causes the cols to be shrinked. You can try with fixed width of the grid (100% ?) with `overflow-x: auto` and fixed width for the cols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have similar issue and followed these two steps:

```
The width of each column should be given in px format only. There will be some issue if it is given in %format.

The ng-grid.css have to be updated to have .ngviewport class with overflow:auto. In my project .ngviewport did not have overflow and this too was a reason for the issue.
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add horizontal scroll bar in case adding extra column add columnDefs like following:

```
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',

    columnDefs: [{ field: "<fieldname>", width: 120},
                { field: "<fieldname>", width: 120 },
                { field: "<fieldname>", width: 120 },
                { field: "<fieldname>", width: 120 }]
  };
```

If the (Total columns*column width) is greater than the width of the ng-grid table which declared in the css part This will give you horizontal scroll bar.

angularJS using the .gridStyle class for the ng-grid by default.

Reference : [ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/)

You can also check here in the Column pinning example : [columnDefs example with pinning](http://plnkr.co/edit/UfFnsZ?p=preview)

In case if there is no columnDefs then columns are trying to auto-fit in to the existing table width so in result the columns are shrinked.

Comment: But is there any way to give the width in percentage type. The example you provided is in px size. Am i right?

Comment: @sms : Yes ! In above example the width in the pixel format. If you want to use the width in % mode you can. In main css of the ng-grid you can use the width in the %.  For Try :: In above example change the width under .gridStyle class from px to %.

Comment: But the problem i am facing now is the data is binded only for the columns that are fit to the grid. The horizontal scrollbar is there now but when i scroll i get empty grid.

Comment: @sms : Either remove enablePinning: true, or make         enablePinning: false, and then try the empty grid problem may be because of pinning.

Comment: still i get the issue. i saw enablepinning causes performance degrading on scroll. But i am not even getting the columns while scroll after any time. Not dealing with performance.

Comment: @sms : Looks like this is a bug related to the version which you used. For upgrading it to ng-grid 3.0, mainly now Module name has changed from ng-grid to ui-grid and for more detail you can refer these links : https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/3.0_UPGRADE.md & https://technpol.wordpress.com/2014/08/23/upgrading-to-ng-grid-3-0-ui-grid/

Comment: Yes. But 3.x is supposed to say as unstabilized version and its not  officially released.

Comment: But the plunker example you gave works for ng-grid perfectly. This is really confusing.

Comment: The issue is like the plunker references to latest ng-grid.css whereas your project uses an old one.